# Cannot display array values in mat-select multiple

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, select, angular-material

I have an array values and the values is seen on Chrome Debugger as shown below:

```
value: Array(3)
    0: EmployeeDto {id: 1, name: "John"}
    1: EmployeeDto {id: 2, name: "Marry"}
    2: EmployeeDto {id: 3, name: "Thomson"}
length: 3
```

And I assign these values to the related variable  as shown below:

```
employees =  this.employees ? this.employees : [];
```

However, although I pass these values by id-name pairs to the `mat-select` [multiple selection](https://material.angular.io/components/select/examples), it does not display these value. But, when I use selected values on the opened window, they are retrieved by their id values and the record can be updated using these id values.

The problem is related to passing these values in a wrong format I think, but as far as I know, the id-value pairs should be passed so that id is used to keep values (for submit) and name is used to display these values. On the other hand, if I pass only name values as array `[...]` they are diaplayed without any problem. So, how should I display these values on `mat-select` [multiple selection](https://material.angular.io/components/select/examples)?

Comment: Please can you paste your whole code here ?so that it's easy to debug

Comment: it's not easy to debug without code like @Sakshi says, it's better if u could reproduce in the stackblitz.
I guess the data isn't available when the component is rendered, so your `mat-select` receive actually `[]`

Comment: thanks for reply, but the data is available before rendering. I just wondered if I should bind as object array containing is and name values as shown above or pass name values by mapping the values above. It will helps me really if you also give an example.

Comment: the following example seems to be similar to my example, but I am not sure where is the mistake in my approach? https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-1e9gsd-34hrwg?file=app%2Fselect-overview-example.html

Comment: I'm not prety suere how is your array, but it's looks like each element of your array is an object that each object has with two properties, use `employees =  this.employees ? this.employees.map(x=>x.EmployeeDto) : [];`

Comment: @Eliseo Yes, correct. I think there is just a little mistake that I use array or object instead od each other.

Comment: Please attentşon that I can list the option list, but cannot make the values as "selected". Maybe I could not explain this point very well :( Any idea?

Comment: I wrote how mannage a mat-select when we has an array of object, I hope this can help you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Update incluying services***

In general, in a mat-select multiple that is feeded whith an array of object we need take account two things
1.- the result (in a FormControl or in a variable using [(ngModel)]) is an array
2.- we general want to store in the variable or in the form control, one property of the object and show anohter

So, a tipical

```
  toppingList: any[] = [
    {id: 1, name: "John"},
    {id: 2, name: "Marry"},
    {id: 3, name: "Thomson"}];
```

need a getter

```
  toppings = new FormControl();

  get toppingsName()
  {
    return this.toppings.value?
              this.toppingList.filter(t=>this.toppings.value.indexOf(t.id)>=0)
              .map(x=>x.name):
              null
  }
```

If we has a service that return an array we can write

```
this.dataService.getToppings1().subscribe((res:number[])=>{
     this.toppings.setValue(res)
})
```

```html
    <mat-form-field appearance="fill">
      <mat-label>Toppings</mat-label>
      <mat-select [formControl]="toppings" multiple>
        <mat-select-trigger>
          {{toppingsName}}
        </mat-select-trigger>
        <mat-option *ngFor="let topping of toppingList" [value]="topping.id">{{topping.name}}</mat-option>
      </mat-select>
    </mat-form-field>
```

Or using ngModel

```
  value:any=null;
  get toppingsNameValue()
  {
    return this.value?this.toppingList.filter(t=>this.value.indexOf(t.id)>=0).map(x=>x.name):null
  }
```

If we has a service that return an string separate by commas with the toppings choose we can do -see that first make a spit, but we need transform this array of string in array of numbers-

```
this.dataService.getToppings2().subscribe((res:string)=>{
     this.value=res.split(',').map(x=>+x)
})
```

```html
    <mat-form-field appearance="fill">
      <mat-label>Toppings</mat-label>
      <mat-select [(ngModel)]="value" multiple>
        <mat-select-trigger>
          {{toppingsNameValue}}
        </mat-select-trigger>
        <mat-option *ngFor="let topping of toppingList" [value]="topping.id">{{topping.name}}</mat-option>
      </mat-select>
    </mat-form-field>
```

Well, we can also that we want an array of object (it's not ussual, remember that always can get the value simply using `this.toppingList.filter(t=>this.toppings.value.indexOf(t.id)>=0`

We can do

```
  toppingsObject = new FormControl();
  get toppingsObjectName()
  {
    return this.toppingsObject.value?this.toppingsObject.value.map((x:any)=>x.name):null
  }
```

Now, our service is going to return an array of object. But we can not use directly an object to feed our control. We need a "compare function". Its only a function that has two arguments. We return true if we considered the two object equals. Some like

```
 compareFn(a:any,b:any){
   if (a.id==b.id) 
     return true
   else
     return false
 }
```

Well, normally we abreviature and write this function like

```
 compareFn=(a:any,b:any)=>a.id==b.id
```

Now our subscription to the service is like

```
this.dataService.getToppings3().subscribe((res:any[])=>{
     this.toppingsObject.setValue(res)
})
```

```html
    <mat-form-field appearance="fill">
      <mat-label>Toppings</mat-label>
      <!--see how use the compareFn-->
      <mat-select [formControl]="toppingsObject" multiple [compareWith]="compareFn">
        <mat-select-trigger>
          {{toppingsObjectName}}
        </mat-select-trigger>
        <mat-option *ngFor="let topping of toppingList" [value]="topping">{{topping.name}}</mat-option>
      </mat-select>
    </mat-form-field>
```

See that in this case [value] is the own "topping"

NOTE: In general we store the data in a dbs as string

In [the stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-qktezp?file=src/app/select-custom-trigger-example.html) I put the three cases

Comment: It is exactly perfect in a word, thank you very much for these wonderful explanations and demo code. I learned many things about multple select wit the help of your detailed explanataions ;) Voted up!

Comment: The only thing that I could not understand exactly is `this.toppingsObject.value.map((x: any) => x.name)` line. In the third example we use object as `[value]` instead of id, but how `this.toppingsObject.value.map((x: any) => x.name)` passes name parameter only I think. Hpw the id parameters are retrieved in html part of this case [value] is the own "topping"?

Comment: `toppingsObjectName` is what we **show** in the edit. `this.toppingsObject` is the formControl, `this.toppingsObject.value` is the value and is an array of object, `map`transform the array of object in an array of string. `map` create a new array in each element of the new array is "something" relationate with the original array. "each" element of the array is only the property "name" of the original

Comment: Yes, but the point I mentioned is that: `this.toppingList.map(x => console.log(x.name));` returns only names. But in this case when we only have name fields, how can we pass id of them  when submitting the form?

Comment: The **second** question is I think `[value]` parameter is used in order to display the select list values that was previously recorded. So, in that case what is the difference between  `[value]="topping"` and `[value]="topping.id"`?

Comment: if you put `[value]="topping", the array is an array of object, if you put `[value]="topping.id"`the array is an array of numbers. If you see the stackblitz, to the rigth is the value of the multiselect, you see in the third that is an array of object

Comment: Su pass, when submiting the form the value of the multiselect -an array-, the functions get toppingsName, get toppingValue or get toppingsObjectName is used **only** to show in the input, but it's not the value.NOTE: if you has a formGroup use a getter to return the formControl

Comment: Thanks it is OK. Assume that for the third select, John and Marry is selected in database and when opening a record of this third person list, John and Marry sill be retrieven as checked. In this scenario: **1)** We fill the list, I think we will bind the list with 3 people via `let topping of toppingList`.Is that true? **2)** How will we mark the selected people on selectlist? Will it be done via `toppingsObjectName` property?

Comment: You rock!!! Many many thanks for your full of detailed and useful explanations.

Comment: @Eliseo ,I have one question in regards to the angular material table can you please help here. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65347251/how-to-show-split-header-in-the-material-table-having-nested-group-of-data-in-an